# String '24/01/2018 13:20:00' was not recognized as a valid DateTime. While other similar strings are converted

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing

I am converting date values I receive in string format to `DateTime` using the following `ParseExact` method:

```
DateTime myValue = DateTime.ParseExact(inputValueString, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The following values pass without a problem:

```
11/01/2018 11:43:00
11/01/2018 11:44:00
23/01/2018 10:05:00
23/01/2018 10:07:00
24/01/2018 12:59:00
```

But after these values I get the following exception:

> String '24/01/2018 13:20:00' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Why is this specific value not working? Is it a hidden character in the string that is causing this?

Comment: use HH instead of hh to parse (24hours instead of 12 hours parsing)

Comment: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/05/05/common-mistakes-in-datetime-formatting-and-parsing/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `HH:mm:ss` for 24h format.